# If $W$ is an irreducible invariant subspace for a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, then so is $gW$ for any $g$ in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H \subset G$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex representation of $G$, i.e. $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ and we are given a homomorphism $\rho : G \to GL(V)$.

**I have a problem solving the following task:**

Show that $G$ acts on the set of $H$-invariant subspaces of $V$. More precisely, show that if $W \subset V$ is an $H$-invariant subspace, so is $gW$ for any $g \in G$. Show that if $W$ is irreducible for $H$ then so is $gW$ for any $g \in G$, and either $gW = W$ or $gW \cap W = \{0\}$. By the first part, $G$ acts on the set of $H$-invariant subspaces of $V$. Show the action factors through $G/H$. Show that the vector space $V$ is the direct sum of $H$-invariant subspaces of the same dimension, each of which is irreducible for $H$.

*Proof:*

First we have to show, that $gW$ is also $H$-invariant. Let $h \in H$, then we have
$$h gW = (ghg^{-1})g W = gh W = gW$$
were we used the normality of $h$ and that $W$ is $H$-invariant.

Now comes the irreducibility. If we assume, that $gW$ is reducible, the so should be $g^{-1}(gW)=W$, which contradicts the assumption, that $W$ is irreducible.

Now comes the part, I have difficulties with...

**For clarification:**
My question is, how to solve this whole exercise. So basically i still have a problem showing that:

1. either $gW = W$ or $gW \cap W = \{0\}$ in the irreducible case.
2. the action factors through $G/H$ and that the vector space $V$ is the direct sum of $H$-invariant subspaces of the same dimension, each of which is irreducible for $H$.

**Edit:**
I dont wanted to leave this question not fully answered, so i tried to show the $G$-invariance, as proposted in the good answer below. Now, first note that $g \in G/H$ is a coset of the form $g := g H, g \in G$. Thus
$$\oplus_{g \in G/H} gW = \oplus_{g \in G} (gH)W.$$
Take $l \in G$, s.th. $\tilde{g}= (lg) \in G$ and as before $\tilde{g}:= \tilde{g}H \in G/H$. We then get
$$l (\oplus_{g \in G/H} gW) =  \oplus_{g \in G} ((lg)H)W =\oplus_{\tilde{g} \in G} (\tilde{g}H)W= \oplus_{\tilde{g} \in G/H} \tilde{g}W$$

Comment: Would you mind clarifying exactly what your question is? You have a long problem, followed by some good progress on it, plus a question in the title that it seems like you've answered, but which is different from the part of your long problem that you haven't addressed yet.

Comment: Yes, of course! Im writing it down at the end of my progress.

Comment: Note that in your proof of $H$-invariance the first identity is not a priori correct. I'd say a better proof would be $$hgW = g(g^{-1}hg)W = gW$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying! Here are some hints:

For (1), you should look at $gW \cap W$. This is an $H$-invariant subspace of $V$ (do you see why?) which is contained in $W$. Now if $W$ is irreducible, what does that tell us about $gW \cap W$?

For (2), the fact that the action factors through $G/H$ is basically the *definition* of $H$-invariance. If you want a more concrete proof, take a coset $gH$ and define $(gH)W \triangleq gW$. You'll need to check that this is well defined, but that follows immediately from the fact that $hW = W$ for every $h \in H$.

Lastly, to get that $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of $H$-irreducible subspaces of the same dimension, I think you need a ~bonus assumption~, namely that $V$ is $G$-irreducible. Otherwise, since $G \vartriangleleft G$, this would be saying that every $G$-rep decomposes as a direct sum of irreducible $G$-reps of the same dimension, which is obviously false. I'm sure if you spend some time with it you can come up with an example for $H$ a *proper* normal subgroup of $G$, and this is probably a good exercise (which I currently don't feel like doing myself :P).

However, if we assume that $V$ is $G$-irreducible, then take your favorite (nontrivial!) $W$ which is $H$-irreducible, and look at $\bigoplus_{G /H} gW$. Can you show that this is a $G$-invariant subspace of $V$? If $V$ is irreducible, do you see why that means it must actually be all of $V$? Then you're done, since the $gW$ are disjoint, $H$-irreducible, $H$-invariant, and all of the same dimension (by work you've done before)!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Ok, first thanks for this answer! There are still some points im not sure about yet.

Comment: For (1), remember that $W$ is "irreducible" if and only if the only subrepresentations are $\{0\}$ and $W$. Since $gW \cap W$ is a subrepresentation, then $gW \cap W$ must be either $\{0\}$ or $W$, which is exactly what you want to show. For (2), you probably _could_ do this with a basis argument, but it's inelegant. The main idea is to use irreducibility of $V$. Can you show that $\bigoplus_{G/H} gW$ is a $G$-subrepresentation of $V$? THen since $V$ is $G$-irreducible, we'll know that $\bigoplus_{G/H} gW$ is either $\{0\}$ or $V$.

Comment: Thank you very much, i now understand what i have to do :)